# How do I analyze each grid regions of a video in OpenCV (Python)?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Here's what I'm trying to mimic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=exXD6wJLJ6s

This guy is separating the video input into many square grids and analyzing each region to know what's going on in that specific region.

For me, it seemed like he was finding the dominant color for each grid. So I tried getting dominant colors on an image with KMean method and it worked well. (I'm trying to 'divide and conquer' the problem, by addressing the problem from the smallest part.)

However, I have no idea how to get dominant color for each grid region of an image. I think I should iterate through each grid square but how?

Furthermore, it seems almost impossible for me to do the above task on a video. Can the same algorithm (detecting dominant color in an image (region)) also apply to real-time detection of a video? Wouldn't it be too sluggish?

I'm really new to OpenCV and I'm basically just following whatever tutorials that seem to be related to my project.

To sum up: I got dominant color from the image following the below tutorial and now I want to do this for each grid of an image/video.

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/05/26/opencv-python-k-means-color-clustering/

This is what I've done so far:

[image: This is what I've done so far]

I drew the grid on MSPaint:

[image: I drew the grid on MSPaint]

Comment: But what exactly you want to do ?

Comment: "To sum up, I got dominant color from the image following the below tutorial and now I want to do this for each grid of an image/video."

Comment: Crop the larger image into smaller chunks, and then do the same.

Comment: @ZdaR  That what I found searching SO before asking this question but that seems like a wrong direction for real-time processing of a video, which is my final goal. (You mean I should crop the image into smaller chunks and save them separately right? That cannot be applied to a 30FPS video to my sense)